# fail2ban ip blocked, yet still login attempts

Tags: debian, security, iptables, fail2ban

everything seems ok, iptables shows its blocked, yet I still get auth attempts

I have configured fail2ban

```
# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
bantime  = 864000
maxretry = 3

[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
```

fail2ban log shows its already blocked

```
2016-01-17 06:25:02,218 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.6
2016-01-17 06:25:03,275 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Log rotation detected for /var/log/auth.log
2016-01-17 06:25:54,330 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Log rotation detected for /var/log/auth.log
2016-01-19 13:21:33,459 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-19 13:21:45,472 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-19 13:22:28,522 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-19 13:22:38,534 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-19 13:22:53,550 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-19 13:23:47,609 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-20 12:58:54,982 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-20 12:59:41,030 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-20 12:59:55,046 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-20 13:00:06,057 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-20 13:00:37,091 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
2016-01-20 13:01:20,137 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
```

iptables -L -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            some_IP_I_need        tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:port_of_websrv state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  some_IP_I_need        0.0.0.0/0            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:port_of_websrv state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain fail2ban-ssh (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

yet, still some auth requests, why?

```
Jan 20 12:59:55 pdwhost sshd[659439]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  user=root
Jan 20 12:59:55 pdwhost sshd[659441]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  user=root
Jan 20 12:59:57 pdwhost sshd[659439]: Failed password for root from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 43728 ssh2
Jan 20 12:59:57 pdwhost sshd[659439]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
Jan 20 12:59:57 pdwhost sshd[659441]: Failed password for root from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 43729 ssh2
Jan 20 12:59:57 pdwhost sshd[659441]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
```

I typically run services on non standard ports if possible. which makes me also wonder, why does this line show port 22 (ssh is on a different port), is this something i need to change somewhere?

```
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
```

also, does it make sense to report this IP? its from choopa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try setting

```
port     = ssh
```

to the port you really use. (I assume that even with running ssh on a non-standard port, you're not changing the value in `/etc/services`, and you probably shouldn't do that anyway.)

Comment: that seems to have solved it, at least for now i cant find any new attempts in the auth file, thank you